# Where is clone() method in sched.h on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, system-calls

I can not find `clone()` in the `sched.h` header file.
Where is it on Mac OS X?

Comment: Any particular reason why you need clone() and not fork()? The man page makes it seem like it's mostly of interest to people making very low-level libraries.

Answer (score 8):

[`man 2 clone`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/clone) says:

> The clone() and sys_clone calls are Linux-specific and should not be used in programs intended to be portable.

Answer (score 2):

clone() is a Linux-specific call and doesn't exist in OSX.