# clone system call OS X not linking - undefined symbols

Tags: c, gcc, fork, clone, ld

I would like to use the `clone` system call on OS X. It's a Unix system call so it shouldn't be a problem, right? I have successfully tried using `fork`, `vfork` and other similar functions. Here is the program I'm trying:

```
#include <sched.h>  //Clone resides here
#include <stdlib.h> //standard library
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int helloWorld();

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int (*functionPointer)() = &helloWorld; //The first argument of clone accepts a pointer to a function which must return int
    void **childStack = (void**)malloc(1024); //We will give our child 1kB of stack space

    clone(functionPointer, childStack, 0, NULL); //First arugment is the function to be called, second one is our stack, CLONE_VM means to share memory, last NULL PID description

    return 0;
}

int helloWorld()
{
    printf("Hello (clone) world!\r\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Compiling with `gcc -o test my_file.c` gives:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_clone", referenced from:
      _main in ccG3qOjx.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Feel free to ignore the comments, since I'm just learning. And one more thing.. if I try to pass `CLONE_VM` in the arguments it doesn't even compile giving me the error:

```
my_file.c: In function ‘main’:
my_file.c:12: error: ‘CLONE_VM’ undeclared (first use in this function)
my_file.c:12: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
my_file.c:12: error: for each function it appears in.)
```

Am I missing an `#include`? If so, which one?

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320174/where-is-clone-method-in-sched-h-on-mac-os-x

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`clone` is specific to Linux, so for OS X you're stuck with `fork`, or use threads if you can manage with that.