# Is there an equivalent to the clone() syscall on macOS?

Tags: c++, macos, system-calls

As [the one in Linux](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html), in which I can pass as parameters the function I want to execute in the child, the memory to be used, etc. I attach an example, in which I'm trying to start a child process that would execute the `chld_func` function using the memory allocated within `stack_memory()`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sched.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

// ...

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    printf("Hello, World! (parent)\n");

    clone(chld_func, stack_memory(), SIGCHLD, 0);
    wait(nullptr);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Maybe I could try to do something similar using `fork()`, but I don't know where to begin.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No equivalent to `clone()`. If you want to implement threading, you should probably use [pthread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_Threads).

Comment: Also, you should specify if you want to do this in C or C++. Tagging with both is ambiguous.

Comment: Oh, sorry, it is in C++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320174/where-is-clone-method-in-sched-h-on-mac-os-x) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20734373/clone-system-call-os-x-not-linking-undefined-symbols) `clone` is specific to Linux.

The macOS [system calls you can do](https://jameshfisher.com/2017/01/31/macos-system-calls/) include `fork` and `vfork`, so you can use one of then.

See also [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/199695) for some reasoning about `clone` and `fork` and read man pages:

- http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html
- http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/vfork.2.html
- http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html